# CSS Vanished in HTML datalist inside a table

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-datalist

[image: webpage]

I'm quite new at web development. Inside a form, I've created this table. In One table data, I need to use a datalist with a placeholder "Establishment:Independent/Chain*"

But

1. It's not covering the whole table column
2. The background image also vanishes

Can someone help me with this problem?

I've written this code

```css
body {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/800");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<td>
  <input list="establishmentType" id="type" placeholder="Establishment : Independant/Chain*" required>
  <datalist id="establishmentType">
                <option value="Independant"></option>
                <option value="Chain"></option>
                </datalist>
</td>
```

Comment: What you provided doesn't seem to demonstrate the problem. Please see [ask] again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
    body {
      font-weight: bold;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/800");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    
table {
      width: 100%;
      
}
    
td {
        width: 50%;
}

td input {
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>test</td>

<td>
      <input list="establishmentType" id="type" placeholder="Establishment : Independant/Chain*" required>
      <datalist id="establishmentType">
                    <option value="Independant"></option>
                    <option value="Chain"></option>
                    </datalist>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

But honestly, I wouldn't use tables for forms.... that's really old and not a good practice anymore.
I would try flexbox instead.

Like so:

```
.row { 
    display: flex
}
.column {width: 50%;}

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
      left
  </div>
  <div class="column">
      right
  </div>
</div>
```

For your rows and columns